# Grid scrolling not come up

Tags: extjs4

My Layout is border layout, 3 panel's north, south, and center, center panel contains grid panel.

The problem is scroll is not coming, if i put outside of viewconfig autoscroll is not coming.

But if i put inside the viewconfig autoscroll true means it is scroll only the data, not column

header, I wanted to scroll the data's along with column header. please help me to resolve the isssue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of code snippet would help clarify the problem

First, it needs to be inside of an Ext.Viewport to get resizable scrolling (if someone minimizes / maximizes scrolling the scroll bar will adjust accordingly). I can't tell if if is already or not.

In the viewport config leave the `layout: border` but add `layout: fit` to the center panel. Don't put it in the viewconfig. That should add scroll bars for the whole grid automatically.